# How to fetch all rows from table with count of specific group?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by

I have a simple table like this

`spatialite> select id, group_id, object_id, object, param from controlled_object;
1|1|150|nodes|0.5
2|1|186|nodes|0.5
3|2|372|nodes|1.0`

The second column is `group_id`. I want to retrieve all entries from the table, plus the count of the group.

```
1|1|150|nodes|0.5|2
2|1|186|nodes|0.5|2
3|2|372|nodes|1.0|1
```

I thought a cross join would be the way to go

```
   SELECT
  *
  , cj.cnt
FROM
  controlled_object
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT group_id) AS cnt
  FROM
    controlled_object
) AS cj
```

But that gives me

```
1|1|150|nodes|0.5|2|2
2|1|186|nodes|0.5|2|2
3|2|372|nodes|1.0|2|2
```

How do I fetch all rows from table including the count of a specific group?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Tag the question with your DBMS. Check if it supports ROW_NUMBER() OVER().

Comment: does not support ``ROW_NUMBER() OVER()``

Answer (score 1):

Join source data with counters, grouped by group_id

```
select c.id, c.group_id, c.object_id, c.object, c.param,cnt from controlled_object  c join
(select group_id,count(*) cnt from controlled_object group by group_id) p on c.group_id =p.group_id  ;
```

Not very good idea for big tables
Sqlite is not very good idea for big tables at all :-)

Comment: the table is very small so performance is not really an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the count with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id,
       group_id,
       object_id,
       object,
       param,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM controlled_object AS co2
        WHERE group_id = controlled_object.group_id)
FROM controlled_object;
```